# Accessing individual cell values in ranges stored in VBA dictionaries

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a table in Excel that I get my dictionary ID in `column A` and right now 
 I am getting the dictionary key from `column B` with the `Cell.Offset(0,1)`  you can see in the code below.

My problem is when I paste the dictionary key (in another workbook) I would like to get more than `column B` (like `column B` to `V`), but I use the value of `column B` for comparison purposes.

So if I store more columns in the key value (as a range for example) I can paste all of them, but I don't have access to my value of `column B` and my test* doesn't work anymore.

*The test is to get the latest iteration of the duplicated item ID in my table. It's what is in the `Else` of the `IF` condition.

```
 Public Function GetLatestRevisions(SearchRng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict            As Object
    Dim Cell            As Excel.Range
    Dim RevisionInDict  As Long
    Dim Revision        As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If SearchRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

    For Each Cell In SearchRng
        If Not dict.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            dict.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21)
        Else
            RevisionInDict = ConvertTextToNumeric(dict(Cell.Value))
            Revision = ConvertTextToNumeric(Cell.Offset(0, 1))
            If Revision > RevisionInDict Then dict(Cell.Value) = Cell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next

    Set GetLatestRevisions = dict
End Function
```

Comment: So you want to capture unique values for each cell your range (B:V) as keys and paste those; what are you adding as the value for the key?  is that part of the issue?

Comment: I don't mind to capture them as keys or as a range if I am able to acces the the first cell of that range before I paste them (which I can't figure how to do).

Comment: Can you breakdown that comment a little further so we can build logic around it?  Specifically "*if I am able to acces the the first cell of that range before I paste them (which I can't figure how to do)*".  Possibly provide info about what your data looks like (an image if possible)?

Comment: No problem! In my code at first I only fetch colomn A & B (item & key). You can see in my code I tried to go and get the range B:V with *Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21)*(instead of only column B). But when i do that this line, dict(Cell.Value), doesn't work anymore to give me the value that is stored in column B which I need to know if what I just fetch is the latest iteration of this particular ID.

Comment: What does `ConvertTextToNumeric` do?  Does it expect a Range as an argument?

Comment: @VictorLalonde does the data always have values in B:V or is it displayed such that the last column is the newest data (up to V)?

Comment: my revisions are in letters so like PA, PB ,PC to compare them I use `ConvertTextToNumeric` to convert them to numbers and then compare them (>). `ConvertTextToNumeric` needs a string in input and outputs a number (long)

Comment: @Cyril Each item is on a different row and each row has data from column A to V. Column A being its ID.

Comment: If `ConvertTextToNumeric` needs a string input then it will fail when `dict(Cell.Value)` returns a Range object.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes This is my problem, sorry I had trouble explaining it :/ . Is there a way to go fetch the string that is stored in the first cell of that range?

Comment: See my edit below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different ways of adding to/updating your dictionary, and they have different results:

```
dict.Add v, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21)

dict(Cell.Value) = Cell.Offset(0, 1)
```

The first line adds `Cell` as a `Range` object.

In the second case you add the `Value` of the cell and not the cell itself.

So, your dictionary may be inconsistent - some values will be Ranges, and some will not.

To illustrate the problem:

```
Dim dict, c As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Set c = Range("A1:B1") 'value = "Hello"|"World"

dict.Add "A", c
Debug.Print TypeName(dict("A")) '>> Range
Debug.Print dict("A")(1)        '>> Hello
Debug.Print dict("A").Cells(2)  '>> World (a little more explicit)

dict("A") = c                   'adds c.Value, not c itself
Debug.Print TypeName(dict("A")) '>> Variant()
Debug.Print dict("A")(1, 1)     '>> Hello
Debug.Print dict("A")(1, 2)     '>> World

'Using Set can correct the problem
Set dict("A") = c               'correctly adds c as Range  
Debug.Print TypeName(dict("A")) '>> Range ***
Debug.Print dict("A")(1)        '>> Hello
Debug.Print dict("A").Cells(2)  '>> World
```

Fixed-up function:

```
Public Function GetLatestRevisions(SearchRng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict            As Object
    Dim Cell            As Excel.Range, v
    Dim RevisionInDict  As Long
    Dim Revision        As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If SearchRng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function

    For Each Cell In SearchRng
        v = Cell.Value
        If Not dict.Exists(v) Then
            dict.Add v, Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21)
        Else
            RevisionInDict = ConvertTextToNumeric(dict(v).Cells(1).Value)
            Revision = ConvertTextToNumeric(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            If Revision > RevisionInDict Then
                Set dict(v) = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 21)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set GetLatestRevisions = dict
End Function
```

Comment: But what if c, in this case, was a range ["hello","hi","whats up"] and I only wanted to update/fetch its first entry. Do you know how to do that. `Debug.Print TypeName(dict("A").Range("A1"))` Is what i tried and didn't work...

Comment: `dict("A").Cells(1).Value`

Comment: I get the run time error 424 "Object requiered" on this line : `RevisionInDict = ConvertTextToNumeric((dict(Cell.Value).Cells(1).Value))` when using this.

Comment: That was what i was trying to explain in my answer here - the first part of your `If` (no existing key) adds a Range object to the Dictionary, but the second part (key already exists: compare versions) may replace the Range with a single value (or variant array if you don't just use a single cell), because it implicitly calls `Range.Value` when you make the update.

Comment: Ok I understand the creation and update of the keys do not produce the same output. Thanks a lot for your time I would never have found this by myself!